# How to size a Tkinter Checkbutton by pixels when there's no text but also no image?

Tags: python, tkinter

A Tkinter `Checkbutton` widget can have a text or an image/bitmap. When using text the `width` and `height` configurations of the widget refer to characters, rather than pixels, but when using an image/bitmap they refer to pixels. I'm using a `Checkbutton` widget with no image nor text - just a plain checkbox. Is there a simple way to have it sized in pixels?

Note: I am familiar with the hack of wrapping it in a `Frame`, but am hoping this is avoidable here, as the widget itself does support by-pixel sizing.

If there's no simple way of instructing the widget to use "image mode" in these circumstances, what's a simple way of feeding it an empty bitmap (if that would at all work)?

In case it matters: I'm using Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a 1x1 image (one pixel wide, one pixel tall). That will cause the size attribute to be based on pixels, and the image you give it will be virtually invisible.

```
import tkinter as tk
...
img = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, width=40, height=40)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bryan. I've tried it and it sort of works, only I see now that the width I assign the widget does *not* include the (un)checked square of the check button itself, so that the whole widget is actually wider than I'm trying to define it to be. Any ideas how to tackle that?